# Using apostrophe in like clause in oracle sql query for wild search

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to search for name that has apostrophe in it, e.g O'Brian and trying to use the below query.

```
select * from <Table Name> where first_name like '%'%';
```

However, I am getting error for invalid identifier

Answer (score 1):

Because Oracle interprets the second `'` as the end of your string, so the remaining part `%'` is beyond the string, and it's parsed as SQL, and obviously it's invalid syntax of SQL.

To prevent this you should escape the middle `'` symbol, in Oracle it's done by typing two consequent apostrophe, so you do `'%''%'`

Comment: Thank you Alex for your quick response, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alternative Quoting Mechanism as `q'[]'`

In your case query should be like this:

```
select * from <Table Name> where first_name like q'[%'%]';
```

Comment: Thank you Atif, Good to know this search mechanism as well